# Counting no of words including punctuation

Tags: python, count, punctuation

I am trying to count the number of words in a string including the punctuation (,/;/./!/?).

So far have been able to to count only the number of words but the punctuation are not getting counted. Tried giving a space before each punctuation using replace but it still is not getting counted. Can someone help me out?

My code:

```
    import re
    input_text = input("Enter the data: ")
    final_text = input_text.replace(',',' ,').replace(';',' ;').replace('.',' .').replace('?',' ?').replace('!',' !')     
    count = len(re.findall(r'\w+', final_text))
    print(count)
```

e.g. for this input

hi. how are you? I am good! what about you? bye!

It should be 16 including all punctuation. But I am getting only 11.

Comment: Count the words, then count the punctuations? Add them up?

Comment: The ident in your code snippet is odd.

Comment: @dgg32 rectified ! Thanks for pointing it out ! And yeah adding them up works just fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
s = "hi. how are you? I am good! what about you? bye!"
result = len(re.findall(r'[^\w\s]|\w+', s))

print(result)   # 16
```

---

`\w+` - will match alphanumeric sequences(including underscore `_`)

`[^\w\s]` - will match all characters except alphanumeric and whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution to your problem without any imports:

```
my_string = "hi. how are you? I am good! what about you? bye!"
space_words = my_string.strip().split(" ")
count = len(space_words)
for word in space_words:
    for character in word:
        if not character.isalpha():
            count += 1
print count
```

Output:

> 16

Comment: This is unsafe since it assumes that only one punctuation character is present for every word. Abbreviations like e.g. or i.e. would break it, also Spanish question marks would fail: ¿Que?. And what if the word contains a number, like deadmau5? Miriam's answer is far safer.